# How to associate data with channels in Netty SimpleChannelInboundHandler

Tags: netty

Could I just have a map with the ChannelHandlerContext.channel() as the key?  Is there a better way to do that?

Comment: What are you trying to do ?

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `ChannelHandlerContext.attr(...).set(...)` and `.get(...)` for this. This allows you to have key / value pairs per `Channel`.